# Extract last 5 mins of information from a log file

Tags: shell, text-processing

My system date format:

```
Thu Jun 13 12:55:18 EDT 2019
```

My log format:

```
193.118.26.141 - - [01/May/2019:00:08:49 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 27
```

Can someone help me, how to get last 5 minutes of logs please?

Comment: You'll need to use a language like gawk or perl or python or ..., that have included date parsing facility. IMO your log format has an unfortunate timestamp format that doesn't make it easy to compare numerically.

Comment: Similar question: [Convert formatted dates to seconds since the epoch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53724/convert-formatted-dates-to-seconds-since-the-epoch)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract logs between the current time and the last 15 minutes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285111/how-to-extract-logs-between-the-current-time-and-the-last-15-minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will need extensive text processing and time manipulations, this should be done using `awk`, but will still need the external `date` command to work.

The following `awk` program (let's call it `parse_log_range.awk`) will work:

```c
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
    "date +%s" | getline now
    close("date +%s")
}

{
    n=match($0,/\[[^]]+\]/)
    tst=substr($0,n+1,RLENGTH-2)

    gsub(/\//," ",tst)  # replace all '/'
    sub(/:/," ",tst)    # replace first ':'
    
    cmd="date +%s -d \"" tst "\""
    cmd | getline tst_s; close(cmd)

    if (now-tst_s<max_age) print
}
```

In the beginning, it will launch the command `date +%s` in the shell to query the current time and store it in a variable `now`.

For each line of the log file, this will

- extract the timestamp as being the element in between `[ ... ]`
- remove the `/` and the first `:` to make the format understandable to `date`
- create a shell command of the form `date +%s -d edited timestamp` which will convert the timestamp into "seconds since the epoch"
- run this command in the shell, and read the result into a variable `tst_s`

It will then check if the timestamp is less than `max_age` away from `now`, where `max_age` is a timespan you have to specify (in your example, 5 minutes = 300 seconds).

Run the command as

```
awk -v max_age=300 -f parse_log_range.awk logfile.txt
```